# PowerBI Filter on multiple fields across multiple data sources

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have work in Tableau for years, but my new employer uses PowerBI and I can not wrap my head around the one relationship only thing.

I have a 2 fields from 5 different datasources I need to be able to filter by.  I have a "main" datasource with the bulk of my datapoints that I have merged in PowerQuery with the other four datasources using a Date field as the 1 relation and a Text field with only two options as the 2 relation.  The Text field contains the names of our company's two business units.

I have set up a PBI report that filters fine on Date, but I need the report to filter on both Date and Business Unit and have the datapoints from all five datasources filter to data only for records that contain the selected Date and Business Unit.  I can not add a Date filter and then add five identical Business Unit filters and present this to my C-suite.

I understand how calculate() works (SQL where).  I understand how filter() works (LOD calc, sorta).  I am using them in some of my measures in the table pictured below.

If this were Tableau, I would probably join on the Date field and blend on the Business Unit field, or blend both fields, or create Parameters and filter on T/F calculated fields.  I tried to figure out the PBI Parameter, but all it looks like is a series of numbers from 1 to 20?  WTF am I supposed to do with that?

[image: Sample Table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Power BI, you need to create a dimensional model. You will have an Organization dimension (table) that has the Business Unit field, and a Date dimension that has dates. Then the keys from the dimension tables are related to the Fact (data) tables. More than likely, if the columns are the same between your five datasources, they might be best combined into a single fact table.

You model should look like this, with you fact table in the middle, and dimension tables in a "star" around them. They call this a "star schema."

[image: Star Schema]

A good model is essential in a Power BI report. Here is a good reference to get started with dimensional modeling in Power BI:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-dimensional-model-report

Comment: -More than likely, if the columns are the same between your five datasources, they might be best combined into a single fact table.-  (The columns aren't all the same - just the Date and Business Unit.  Can't union)  How do I do this?  I merged the five queries in Power Query and I expected one big table like Tableau.  I guess I could build dummy tables as you say.  Would you suggest Power Query for that?

Comment: If the columns are different, it's probably better to leave them separate. FYI, in Power Query, append is union, merge is join. You do want a single dimension table with all business units still, and then set up a relationship from the BU and date dimensions to all five fact tables. It needs to be a "one-to-many" relationship, meaning that the business unit column in the dimension contains no blanks or duplicates. Then use the business unit field from the dimension table in the reports, and it is best practice to hide the business unit field in the fact tables.